# c# lambda property map to string

Tags: c#, lambda

I have data in a dictionary similar to below:

"key 1" : "data 1",

"key 2" : "data 2",

"key 3" : "data 3",

and a class:

```
public class OuputClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Using lambda I want to be able to easily map key name for each property and create new instance of class passed in.

```
var result = MapData<Class1>(x => x.Field1 = "key 1", x.Field2 = "key 3")
```

In the function MapData I want to be able to process the 2 properties passed in the function and return a new instance of OutputClass with the properties set. (Field1 = "data 1" and Field2 = "data 3")

I have looked into using Func and IQueryable but cant seem to get this to work elegantly

Thanks for any help.

Below is example of ToObject function:

```
 public static T ToObject<T>(Func<T, IQueryable> mapper) where T : new()
    {
        //code to create the class (more complex then this)
        var data = new T();

        //if mapper needed then loop through properties specified and use string mapped to each property
        foreach (var item in .....)
        {
            //code to get value needed to set property
            var mappedstring = ...... //get string mapped to property
            var newpropvalue = ...... //use mapped string to access dictionary value;

            //set property of instance
            data.... = newpropvalue;
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Show what you have got so far.

Comment: What is wrong with `x.Field1 = d["key 1"]`, where `d` is the dictionary?

Comment: Why you need `MapData` method? Just create `OuputClass` instance with values from dictionary?

Comment: ok. so apologies for my question. all responses do answer it perfectly. I tried to simplify the question to make it easier. The MapData will be quite complex and may apply the mapping at different times.

Comment: From what you've described I'd expect something like `MapClass((x, y) => new OutputClass { Field1 = x, Field2 = y })`, but it's rather vague...can you clarify that `MapData()` is responsible for calculating the two property values x and y but you don't want it bound to only being able to create an `OutputClass`?

Comment: Please see example of ToObject function. The parameter ive specified is what I need to change. Potentially have this as params? so can pass multple mapping?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method like this:

```
    public T MapData<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        var res = func();
        return res;
    }
```

And call the method like this

```
    var dic= new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //Fill Dictionary

    MapData<OuputClass>(() => new OuputClass { Field1 = dic["Key 1"] , Field2 = dic["Key 2"] });
```

I hope help you

Comment: What's the point, isn't just creating `var result = new OutputClass { Field1 = dic["key1"], Field2 = dic["key2"] }` easier?

Comment: `public T MapData<T>(Func<T> func) => func();` What? Thats some special Method that does exactly what you ask.

Comment: Yes @SeM, it's easier but maybe programmer wants to do other something in `MapMethod` that we don't know.

Comment: From his question _"In the function MapData I want to be able to process the 2 properties passed in the function and return a new instance of OutputClass with the properties set. (Field1 = "data 1" and Field2 = "data 3")"_ it seams that he don't want to do anything inside method.

Comment: Anyway, I think this method is the answer but the question is low level